# Discover SoundCloud user name

Tags: soundcloud

I have a SoundCloud **client_id** that I would like to know the **user_id** or **user name**. Actually I have a full link to a track. Is there anyway I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're asking is with a track link, find the user_id and username of the uploader of a track.

If you know the full soundcloud.com track URL, hit the `/resolve` endpoint.  For reference, I will be using this URL: https://soundcloud.com/madanofficial/the-police-walking-on-the-moon-j-art-madan-remix

```
HTTP GET: https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2Fmadanofficial%2Fthe-police-walking-on-the-moon-j-art-madan-remix&client_id=[YOUR client_id]
```

The resulting JSON:

```
{
  "status": "302 - Found",
  "location": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/147986343.json?client_id=[YOUR client_id]"
}
```

When we hit the SoundCloud API again with the `/tracks` endpoint, just parse the `user` object that is returned.

```
 "user": {
    "id": 44553705,
    "kind": "user",
    "permalink": "madanofficial",
    "username": "Madan.",
    "uri": "https://api.soundcloud.com/users/44553705",
    "permalink_url": "http://soundcloud.com/madanofficial",
    "avatar_url": "https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000098677604-mwg7te-large.jpg?e76cf77"
  }
```